# using binary search to count occurrences

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

assume I have sorted array A in length n so 1
I need to write pseuodocode of a program that give output of all occurrences of each element.
the algorithm runtime has to be maximum k(c1+c2*log(n)).

example - A=[1,1,2,2,2,5,5,5,5] ----> (1,2)(2,3)(5,4)

I thought about using binary search when the first element I want to count is A[1] and I need to find his last occurrence.
then the next element is A[last occurrence index + 1] and so on.

I have a bit difficult with the idea and writig it down as pseuodocode.

tnx

Comment: What specific problem do you have? The idea itself of finding the first and the last occurrence using binary search is correct.

Comment: regular binary seacrh will give me the index of specific number, but now I have the same number in some indexes - how do I modify the binary seacrh to find only the last one every time? @user2040251

Comment: Do you need to count "how many occurrences of X" or "which numbers are there and count of every one" ?

Comment: which numbers are there and count of every one

Comment: See this: http://www.mycodeschool.com/work-outs/binary-search/5

Comment: @EmmadKareem - that answer on "how many occurrences of X" but I need the second option

Comment: If you want to count occurrences of every element (i.e. there are two 1's, three 2's, four 5's, etc.), then in the general case you can't do it faster than O(n). The binary search method *could be* faster if there are many items with duplicates, but if every item in the array is unique, the binary search method will require O(n log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive algorithm, it gets left and right position and calculates middle position. Going deeper if there is number change, en edge. Up to here it is simple binary search. But once it detects (on distance=1) an edge, change of numbers, it will return it in 4 values: 'what number sequence ended', 'on what position', 'what started', 'on what position'. Parent node then merges these 4 values from left and right side and if it detects complete sequence 'in the middle', it immediately prints it and pass just ending edge (from left side) and starting edge (from right).

Comment: not sure I understand - what happened if the is no change of number between the middle and the first elememt?

Comment: Then it will not go deeper in this part. It have to go deeper only in parts with an edge somewhere inside. That is the optimization over algorithm "walk over all elements and count occurrence of current number".

Comment: Then it have to return information of found edges to parent (fallbeck of recursion calling). Parent will merge info from left and right side, printing finished sequence if he can and passing two remaining edges to grand-parent.

Comment: @john - Scrap it. Now that I think about it, solution can be more simple. No need for merging and stuff. When going deeper, always go left side first and depth-first. Once you find edge, save it in global variable. Once another edge is found, you can expect it being next in order, thus print the info and remember new edge. Of course omit processing parts with no number change - no edge.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve that asymptotic complexity.
The reason is no matter what algorithm it is, When all the n elements are distinct, It has to return all the elements.That implies it has to read all of them.Of course, this operation takes O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of occurrences for one entry in O(log(n))

```
static int count(int[] array, int target, int start, int end, Func<int, int, bool> compare)
    {
        if (end < start) { return start; }

        int m = (start + end) / 2;

        if (compare(target, array[m])) { return count(array, target, start, m - 1, compare); }
        else { return count(array, target, m + 1, end, compare); }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 3, 8, 12, 12, 12, 25, 88 };
        int r1 = count(a, 12, 0, a.Length - 1, (x1, x2) =>
            {
                return x1 < x2;
            });

        int r2 = count(a, 12, 0, a.Length - 1, (x1, x2) =>
        {
            return x1 <= x2;
        });

        Console.Out.WriteLine("count=" + (r1 - r2).ToString());
    }
```